# iOS9 タグの追加を提案します

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ

タグ追加の権限がないのでiOS9タグの追加を提案させていただきます。
本日私が投稿した [iOS9 Share ExtensionからOpen URLを実行する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21529/ios9-share-extension%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89open-url%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) でiOS9タグがないので気づいた次第です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

該当記事に付けることが妥当だと思いましたので付けておきました。

タグ [ios9](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios9)